# Limit of a sequence with binomial coefficient. Can I use Stirling?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I was trying to solve this limit:

$\lim_\limits{n\to \infty} \binom {3n}{n}^{1/n} $

I solved it with Cesaro theorem:

$\lim_\limits{n\to \infty} \binom {3n}{n}^{1/n} $= $\lim_\limits{n\to \infty} \frac{((3(n+1))!}{(2(n+1))(n+1)!}\frac{2n!n!}{3n!}= \frac{27}{4}$

But when I have tried to use Stirling I arrived to the form $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}(\frac{27}{4}(\frac{3}{4\pi n})^{1/2})^{1/n}=1$

Surely I've made a mistake. In order to arrive to the form that I have writed before I wrote the limit as $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}(\frac{(3n)!}{n!(2n)!})$ and then I sobstituted to all the terms the Stirling approximation.

Comment: Well, what happens when you try applying Stirling?

Comment: With Stirling I wasn't able to solve it. But I just had an idea. Can I use Cesaro theorem and equal $\lim a(n)^{1/n}$ to $\frac{a(n+1)}{a(n)}$ ?

Comment: Stirling will be fine. One can instead use less fancy estimates of $\ln(n!)=\ln 1+\ln 2+\cdot +\ln n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a small typo somewhere. Since using the Stirling approximation
$$n!\sim\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\sqrt{2\pi n}$$yields

> \begin{align*}
> \binom{3n}{n}&=\frac{(3n)!}{n!(2n)!}\\
> &\sim\left(\frac{\left(\frac{3n}{e}\right)^{(3n)}\sqrt{6\pi n}}{\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{2n}{e}\right)^{(2n)}\sqrt{4\pi n}}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}\\
> &\sim\left(\left(\frac{27}{4}\right)^n\sqrt{\frac{3}{4\pi n}}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}\\
> &\sim\frac{27}{4}\left(\sqrt{\frac{3}{4\pi n}}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}\\
> &\sim\frac{27}{4}
> \end{align*}